# Delete a constraint from a view in swift programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

Is there any way that I can remove a constraint programmatically? By remove I mean delete a constraint not setting it to 0.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can deactivate costraint `yourconstraint.isActive = false`, pretty much the same thing as deleting.

Comment: no it is not working actually i am changing some other constraints that are creating conflict so need to delete a constraint to resolve the layout issue. Already tried that.